# Pass C# variable and use it as a Column Value in SQL Statement Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I need to use the value of a variable as one of my fields in my SQL insert query that I am generating.
In PHP I do this:

```
if($currency = "USD")
{
 $columntoinsert = "USD_Currency";
} 
else
{
 $columntoinsert = "";
}
```

Then in my SQL statement I would execute the query like so:

```
$sqlinsertpayment = sqlsrv_query($connect,"INSERT INTO Payments_TBL(column1,column2,$columntoinsert,columnn)VALUES(????)",$params) or die("An error occurred trying to execute the statement");
```

I want to do the same in C#. I have the following code to set the column I want to use

```
var amountfield = "";
  if (save_currency != "USD")
    {
      amountcolumn = "Amount";

     }
  else
   {
      amountcolumn = "USD_Amount";
   }
```

But I can't execute my sql query in since trying to use `amountcolumn` in the query string generates an `Invalid column name` error which is expected. How can I use the variable in this manner:

```
var sql = new sqlCommand("INSERT INTO Payments_TBL(column1,column2,myc#variablevaluehere,column3,....)Values(@value,@value,@value)",new sqlConnection(conn));
```

Open to other alternatives. All help will be appreciated.

Comment: Parameterize the sql would be my suggestion

Comment: I don't think specifying columns in parameters will work to be used in the query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the value for `amountfield` comes from your code logic, you can safely do this:

```
var sql = new sqlCommand(String.Format("INSERT INTO Payments_TBL(column1,column2,{0},column3,....)Values(@value,@value,@value)", amountcolumn),new sqlConnection(conn));
```

But never do things like this with strings coming from your users because that would make you open for SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks dude. Worked like a charm. Learned something new today.

Comment: Actually the value does not come from the user directly but from the database and it was checked for any xss vulnerabilities or sql injection before saving.

Answer (score 3):

Its

```
var amountfield = save_currency != "USD" ? "Amount" : "USD_Amount";

var sql = new sqlCommand("INSERT INTO Payments_TBL(column1,column2," 
+  amountcolumn + 
",column3,....)Values(@value,@value,@value)",new sqlConnection(conn));
```

OR

```
var sql = new sqlCommand(
                   String.Format("INSERT INTO Payments_TBL(column1,column2,  
                   {0},column3,....)Values(@value,@value,@value)", amountfield), 
                   new sqlConnection(conn));
```